# Save slx model to previous mdl format

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a slx model that was created in simulink R2013b. Is there any way of saving that file to the mdl format in order to open it in Simulink R2010a? I tried to save it to mdl with the menu in Simulink R2013b, but it failed when trying to open it in Simulink R2010a.

Comment: There's an option to select .mdl in the Save-As dialog in Simulink. Have you tried this?

Comment: @RyanJ Yes I did, like I said in my question.

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that. Apologies...

Comment: Basically there is no compartibiliry if a block has changed, what error do you get?

Comment: @Daniel you mean if my model now use 2013 functionnalities? I don't think it does use new 2013 features.

Comment: @m_power: What error message?

Comment: @Daniel Matlab crash, no error message (Windows application crash msg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from the Simulink editor window by going to

**File -> Export model to -> Previous version**

and selecting the version of the model you need.